# How many different phase portal challenges are there?

Tags: torchlight-2

Does anyone know how many different phase portal challenges there are in Torchlight 2 (and if so, what each one is)? They seem to be few and far between (and are typically difficult), but the rewards are usually worth the effort.

**Update:** I should also point out that a few of them appear to be act-specific. I ran into a challenge last night in Act 3 that I hadn't seen before, and which was set in an Act-3 like bog.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I am going to attempt to catalog the phase beast challenges that I am aware of. At the moment, I have a list of 14 challenges. Let me know if you know of any corrections or additions that need to be made here, and I'll add them. I've finally added the challenges added in 1.17.

### Act 1 (6 Challenges)

- **Stay Close to Raise the Totems** - Stand close to each of three totems as they rise out of the ground. *Reward:* One golden chest for each totem you raise
- **Vanquish Your Foes With Haste** - Destroy as many enemies as quickly as you can (?). *Reward:* 1 small chest + 1 medium chest + 2 golden chests
- **Poison the Spider Nests** - Poison several spider nests while battling the spiders that each one spawns. *Reward:* Gold + 1 golden chest
- **Ignite Braziers in Order** - Light the braziers in the correct order, while battling enemies. *Reward:* Gold + 2 small chests + 1 medium chest
- **Protect the Crystals From the Goblin Hordes** - Protect five ember crystals from goblin enemies. *Reward:* 1 small chest for the first crystal + 1 medium chest for each crystal you save (though I have yet to protect all four crystals)
- **Navigate the Maze** - This challenge was added in version 1.17. Navigate a watery maze, collecting all three mysterious gems if you can. *Reward:* 3 medium chests + 1 golden chest, which is only available if you collect all 3 mysterious gems

### Act 2 (7 Challenges)

- **Choose a Door** - Battle several waves of monsters, get the dropped key, and pick one of three doors. *Reward:* One of the following, depending on the door you choose: (a) nothing, (b) medium amount of gold + a few chests, or (c) large amount of gold + a few large chests
- **Jackalbeast Gauntlet** - Run the gauntlet, collecting gold and fighting Jackalbeasts as you go. *Reward:* Gold + 1 small chest + 2 medium chests + random items
- **Pirate Gauntlet** - Run through the ancient pirate ships, collecting gold and battling skeleton pirates along the way. *Reward:* Gold + 6 small chests + 2 medium chests + random items
- **Slime Trio** - Defeat the three giant slimes. *Reward:* Gold + three chests
- **Survive in the Arena** - Survive the enemies in the arena. *Reward:* Gold
- **Dig for Buried Treasure** - This challenge was added in version 1.17. Use shovels to dig for buried treasure among 20 marked places. Reward locations are random, and not all X marks have treasure (some produce a mine, some produce another shovel, and some produce nothing). *Reward:* 1 big + 3 small treasure chests (only available if you find their hidden locations)
- **Avoid the Lava** - This challenge has several chests at various height levels.  The goal is to get as many chests as you can while staying out of the rising lava.

### Act 3 (4 Challenges)

- **Defeat the Troll** - Defeat the champion-level troll that spawns. *Reward:* Gold + 2 small chests + 1 medium chest
- **Defeat the Witches** - Defeat the two champion-level witches. *Reward:* Gold + 2 medium chests
- **Varkolyn Gauntlet** - Run the gauntlet, fighting varkolyn enemies and collecting gold along the way. *Reward:* Gold + 5 small chests + 3 medium chests + random items
- **Survive the Attack** - Survive an attack by a number of enemies, mines, and robots. *Reward:* Gold + 3 small chests + 1 medium chest

If there's a fifth challenge in act 3, I have yet to find it.

Comment: It looks like patch 1.17.x has added new phase challenge rooms, so this list will be updated as soon as I've stumbled upon them.

Comment: You definitely get one chest per crystal on the protect the crystals challenge.  I've saved them all.

Comment: I had a Door #1, Door #2, and Door #3. It was Door #2 for me. It was ONE BIG CHEST with much much gold, and almost a dozen items, followed by 2 small chests with items and gold. I received a total of 22 items from this event. 8 rare items, 6 enchanted items, and 8 normal, white lettered items.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the ones who know how many phase beast challenges are only Runic Games staff, however this is what I found about phase beast challenges during my gameplay:

- Only 1 phase beast challenge can be found in each map(not dungeon).
- you can always found it in the bigger map(temple steppes/frost hills/salt barrens/blightbogs etc), and sometimes on pathway map(the more linear and smaller map).
- all of them are act-specific. I haven't found one that is not.

Answer (score 0):

Even after the latest patch, there are still 3 Phase Beast challenge rooms tucked away in the game that never appear. One is a graveyard where you have to smash the tomb stones within a time limit, one is a frozen bandit camp where you have to burn firewood to keep warm and another is an alternate take on the luminous arena. All of these have been fixed and enabled in the Unearthed Arcana mod.